Blazor Server .NET 8 HttpContext to get token for id_token
I am trying to upgrade from Blazor Server App from .Net 6 to 8.
This is the code in .Net 6:
_Host.cshtml
var context = HttpContext.Request.HttpContext;
var token = await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.GetTokenAsync(context, "id_token");

However in .Net 8, there is no more _Host.cshtml. So I had move the code above to App.razor in OnInitializedAsync() but the id_token is always null.
May I know what should I change?
Expected to get the id_token. That will be used to do a custom authentication and authorisation. So getting id_token is crucial.

In .net 6 you should have put this code in the @{..} of _Host.cshtml. So in .net 8, you could do it in App.razor like below:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
...
@{
    var token = httpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? httpContext {get;set;}
}

Test result

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor
